# VBA error 3704: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am making a sub, to download data from DWH into Excel, using many queries: their scripts are written right in cells.

It's all going fine, until query 3.1. ending with "3704: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

I tried "SET NOCOUNT ON" and it helped with previous queries, but not now.

I guess my connection is also fine as other queries work.

Also SQL script of 3.1 is in attachment.

```
Sub update_GF_New_Param_3()

Dim sConnString As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection    
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset       
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command        
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter          
Dim a As String

user_name = Environ$("UserName")


' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=***;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=***;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
'GF part
 
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'1. 
a = Sheets("4.GF draft").Cells(1, 1).Value
conn.CommandTimeout = 0
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute(a)
Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("A5:F55").ClearContents
Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rs
 
'1.1 
a = Sheets("4.GF draft").Cells(1, 2).Value
Set rs = conn.Execute(a)
Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("AA1:AB300").ClearContents
Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("AA1").CopyFromRecordset rs
   
'3.1 
a = Sheets("4.GF draft").Cells(1, 10).Value
Set rs = conn.Execute(a)
Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("A630:F687").ClearContents
Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("A630").CopyFromRecordset rs
 
 
Set cmd = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe your recordset is closed before getting to ``3.1``.  Try running step by step  a and see what happens.

Comment: Hello, Elio. I've tried "step by step" and it ends up on "Sheets("4.GF draft").Range("A630").CopyFromRecordset rs". I am sure, something's wrong with query.

Comment: What is `a`  each time?  Try `rs.open a,conn,1`

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. Found out the solution: just added "set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF" in query.